# Firebase specific node read and write

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I implemented on a website a form to create firebase users and add a node in the firebase database for the user based on a selected State in the form. 
So for example, if the user chooses 'Hawaii' in the form and then create the account, the account information will be stored in "Hawaii/id" in the firebase db.

```
// JSON structure
    {
      "Hawaii": {
        "place1Id": {
          //infos
        },
        "place2Id": {
          //infos
        }
      },
      "New York": {
        "place1Id": {
          //infos
        },
        "place2Id": {
          //infos
        }
      }
    }
```

My problem is how to make sure that later on when the user will add information to his account, with provided credentials from the previous account creation, this information will be stored in the correct node (Hawaii for example)

I have tried to make a comparison between current user id and keys from States nodes but my database is quite large (and will become larger) so it is taking up to 10 seconds for the code to determine in which node of the database the user is.
And the same process has to occur on each page so it is not the good solution.

```
var placesRef = firebase.database().ref();
    placesRef.once("value", function(snpashot) {
      if (snpashot.child("Hawaii").hasChild(user.uid)) {
        console.log("Place is in Hawaii");
        activiteRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Hawaii").child(user.uid);
      }});
```

Can you please help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you may find Firestore is a better fit. In any case, store addresses in a sub-node of `users > uid`. This way, the user can have multiple addresses, say home and office.

Comment: I already tried to do users > uid but with firebase. The main problem is that I want iOS app users to only see places near them. I tried geofire or to download all the database and then display only the nearest places but my database is so large that it it taking more than 10 seconds for the places to be downloaded on the app. Would it be faster with Firestore ?

Comment: Geofire/Firebase works great for your use case. I got it working on this app. Click the map icon and type in San Francisco to see it work. https://getaa.org

Comment: I have more than 50k entries, are you sure it will not be slow ?

Comment: Read geofire documentation?...

Comment: I already did and actually I have tried it and it was slow with 10k entries. Maybe I did something wrong. I’ll give it another try

Comment: Geofire [doesn't mention limits](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md) but Firebase RT DB [does say up to 75,000,000 max](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits), so 50,000 should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you're keying on `uid`, you don't need to do anything more than the line you already have:

```
activityRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Hawaii").child(user.uid);
```

This is the direct reference to the node you want (if I'm understanding you correctly). You can read the data:

```
activityRef.once('value').then(snap => console.log(snap.exists, snap.val());
```

Which will be `null` if the user has never written there, but will contain data otherwise. You can also perform other operations like `update()` to change the data at this location.

There's no need to perform the top level query to check if the node already exists -- you can just read it directly.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand properly your answer (not English native here) but my main problem is that I have 50 nodes, one for each State. And all users will have access to a CMS I developed, with an account I created for them and data in the node of the State in which they are. So how can I make sure that when someone is login in, he will edit data from his node (in the corresponding State node) ? I can achieve this with the last line of code you gave me ?

Comment: You would want to use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to ensure that users can only write to their own `uid`. You may also want to look at [how to structure your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure).

Comment: So if I use security rules to ensure users can only write on their uid I can do something like this : activityRef = firebase.database.ref() and then do a .once on activityRef without the need to specify in which State the place is ? To sum up: .once on firebase.database.ref() will work the same way as firebase.database.ref().child(‘stateOfThePlace/uid’) by automatically determining in which State (node) the user info are ? Thank you for helping me by the way !